# How to deploy a Gradio app publicly using a static ip?

Tags: python, server, web-applications, gradio

Let's say I have a computer that has a static public ip. How can I deploy a gradio app using my computer as server?

I've seen solutions like:

```
interface.launch(share=True, server_name=<server_name>, server_port=<server_port>)
```

Comment: https://www.gradio.app/guides/running-gradio-on-your-web-server-with-nginx

Comment: Cite your reference -- what web URL encouraged you to call `.launch()` in that way? What went wrong when you attempted it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to open the needed port in your router and enable port forwarding, and just type the ip with port and you are good to go --> network part